# Elegant way to get min and max using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
op1 = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
'date' : ['1/1/2017','1/1/2017','1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/2/2017','1/2/2017','1/3/2017','1/3/2017','1/3/2017','1/4/2017','1/4/2017','1/4/2017','1/5/2017','1/5/2017','1/5/2017',
         '1/6/2017','1/6/2017','1/6/2017'],
'val' :[5,5,11,10,5,7,16,12,11,21,23,26,6,8,5,11,10,3]
})
```

What I would like to do is get the `min` and `max` for each subject every day.

**Though my code works below**, **I feel this can be written in a much better way**

```
t1 = op1.groupby(['subject_id','date'])['val'].max().reset_index()
t2 = op1.groupby(['subject_id','date'])['val'].min().reset_index()
t1.merge(t2,on=['subject_id','date'],how='inner',suffixes=('_max', '_min'))
```

The output should look like given below. Though my code works, it isn't elegant I feel. Is there any other way to write the `max` and `min` in one line?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with tuples for new columns names and aggregate functions:

```
df = (op1.groupby(['subject_id','date'])['val']
         .agg([('val_max', 'max'),('val_min', 'min')])
         .reset_index())
print (df)
   subject_id      date  val_max  val_min
0           1  1/1/2017       11        5
1           1  1/2/2017       10        5
2           1  1/3/2017       16       11
3           2  1/4/2017       26       21
4           2  1/5/2017        8        5
5           2  1/6/2017       11        3
```

In pandas [0.25+](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling) is possible use `named aggregation`:

```
df = (op1.groupby(['subject_id','date'])
         .agg(val_min=pd.NamedAgg(column='val', aggfunc='min'),
              val_max=pd.NamedAgg(column='val', aggfunc='max'))
         .reset_index())
```